# Search query returns "0 questions tagged" until you refresh it a few times

Tags: bug, tags, search

Ever since I added 2 new tags to my search query (about a week ago), it gives me this problem where I have to refresh the page 3 or 4 times before it shows all questions again. Refreshing can be done by either F5 or clicking 'newest', it doesn't make any difference.

This is very annoying for obvious reasons. Those two extra tags ([sql](/questions/tagged/sql) and [plsql](/questions/tagged/plsql)) brought the total amount of questions caught by my search query to just above 2 million, if that makes any difference.

What's causing this?

Browser: Google Chrome 36.0.1985.143 m

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I [remarked here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269298/23354), searching based on large quantities of tags (whether inclusive or exclusive) can have performance implications; and for that reasons (as a QOS aid) the system offers much less redundancy when you include more than 5 tags: it doesn't allow the load to impact more than one server. I assume that the two new tags you've added made the overall query expensive enough to cause it to go beyond the (fairly short) timeout. We let the query *finish*, though - and cache the results after that - which is probably why it is working after 3 or 4 times.

Options:

- use a slightly aggressive query, perhaps doing 2 *separate* searches for half the tags
- we do some overhaul work on this part of the system - *not* a trivial undertaking

Comment: A third option might be to just say "Hey, you're being a little needy and you hit the timeout" (in some more eloquent form) so it's more clear why the page is being untruthful about there being 0 results.

Comment: Could you add timestamp to the query? Say I want to search for those tags only > 1/1/2014. I get the 0 message a all the time, and would not like to split it up.

Comment: @Yuriy what sort are you using?

Comment: I use stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 or asp.net or linq or generics or .net or best-practices or model-view-controller or asp.net-mvc or reflection or attributes or codedom or code-golf or jquery or wcf or puzzle or delegates or anonymous-types or dynamic or regex or ajax or multithreading or sql or linq-to-xml or linq-to-objects or algorithm or marklogic

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer your question, I use Newest

Comment: @Yuriy then due to how we store it, a time cap in unlikely to help. Basically, it is a scenario that needs some dedicated time - it is not trivial.